# git: 'credential-' is not a git command after installing SourceTree

Tags: git, macos, terminal, atlassian-sourcetree

I use git right off the terminal on my Macbook.

I recently install SourceTree as a GUI tool for git. But right after that, I realize SourceTree changed my local git repository configuration and my command git push, git pull or git fetch have it's behaviour changed.

Now I get this output for those commands.

```
git: 'credential-' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
    credential
```

Can anyone help me with that? My repo is hosted on GitHub and right after this strange output the command runs correctly.

Comment: Are there any visible changes to your `.bashrc` file?

Comment: I don't have this file in my home directory.

Comment: run `git config --global -e` and check
if it does not work then try `git config --remove-section credential`

Comment: `git config --remove-section credential` fix the issue. Thank you @rahulmishra

Comment: Ok, I  posted it as an answer please accept it Thanks!

Comment: Accepted! Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Issue get resolved by `git config --remove-section credential`

Thanks!