# git: 'credential-manager' is not a git command

Tags: git

I have a server running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS. I want to save my git credentials, so I don't have to enter them every time. I run the following command:

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

Then I `git pull` and get:

```
user@host:~/project$ git pull
git: 'credential-manager' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
usage: git credential-store [<options>] <action>

    --file <path>         fetch and store credentials in <path>

Username for 'https://gitlab.com':
```

After that I'm being asked for my username and password. And then the same error is printed.

I've already repeated the same process several times, unsetting the `credential.helper` option with:

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

Comment: What does `git config credential.helper` say, in the folder of that repository?

Comment: `git config credential.helper` outputs `store`

Comment: `git config --get-all credential.helper` will show that you have two of them set. Git tries them in order. The first one fails as "not found"; the second one fails due to a missing argument. Use `git config --show-origin` to find where the two commands are defined.

Comment: The information from @torek combined: `git config --show-origin --get-all credential.helper`

Answer (score 36):

I executed this command

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

and at this time I already got no error after git pull command.
I have git of version  2.34.1.windows.1

Comment: This should be set as the best answer. I have tried many other solutions and they didn't work.

Comment: This. This is definitely the best answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

The [documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage) shows the command

```
$ git config --global credential.helper 'store --file ~/.my-credentials'
```

So it seems likely that `git` simply executes the command set in `credential.helper`. The command *you* set is just `store` ... which requires a mandatory argument ... which you haven't provided.

This explains why the `store` command (actually `git credential-store`) isn't working as you expect.

I don't know where the complaint about `credential-manager` comes from - most likely it's just mis-reporting all failure states as "not a git command".

Answer (score 1):

It may be that the credential-manager command you are using is either deprecated or is for a different OS.
I ran into this problem after following a blog about saving the GitHub credentials and then realized that they were for Windows instead of Linux.
It could also be that I didn't pass the appropriate arguments as Useless stated in his/her answer.

Either way, I solved it by going into ~/.gitconfig and removing the line at the end about the credential manager.  Attempt this at your own risk though.  I don't know if there are unforeseen consequences.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50418743/6522746) helped me resolve the problem with the command below:

```sh
git config --remove-section credential
```